# Unable to install postgresql via terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, installation

I was trying to re-install postgresql in my desktop [ it was actually working fine before] and I'm getting the following error after entering sudo apt-get install postgresql
I tried many possibilities, I removed all traces of previously installed version as shown in this tutorial https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052079/unable-to-install-postgresql-9-6-in-ubuntu-18-04

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
**Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  pgdg-keyring postgresql-14 postgresql-client-14 postgresql-client-common postgresql-common
Suggested packages:
  postgresql-doc postgresql-doc-14
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  pgdg-keyring postgresql postgresql-14 postgresql-client-14 postgresql-client-common postgresql-common
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 17.7 MB/17.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 59.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg/main amd64 postgresql-client-common all 232.pgdg20.04+1
  404  Not Found [IP: 217.196.149.55 80]
Err:2 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg/main amd64 postgresql-client-14 amd64 14.1-2.pgdg20.04+1
  404  Not Found [IP: 217.196.149.55 80]
Err:3 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg/main amd64 postgresql-common all 232.pgdg20.04+1
  404  Not Found [IP: 217.196.149.55 80]
Err:4 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg/main amd64 postgresql-14 amd64 14.1-2.pgdg20.04+1
  404  Not Found [IP: 217.196.149.55 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/pool/main/p/postgresql-common/postgresql-client-common_232.pgdg20.04+1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 217.196.149.55 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/pool/main/p/postgresql-14/postgresql-client-14_14.1-2.pgdg20.04+1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 217.196.149.55 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/pool/main/p/postgresql-common/postgresql-common_232.pgdg20.04+1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 217.196.149.55 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/pool/main/p/postgresql-14/postgresql-14_14.1-2.pgdg20.04+1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 217.196.149.55 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?**
```

Comment: Looks to me like the repo server(s) where temporarily not reachable. I just tried and it worked. Try again.

Comment: I tried to install it again, but no luck.

Comment: What happens if you go to `http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt` directly through a browser? Also if you `ping 217.196.149.55`?

Comment: shows 404 error

Comment: Then something is blocking your outbound access to that address, as I have no problem reaching it. You will need to talk to your network administrators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if the repository server is outdated/down. Try selecting a different repository mirror.
[image: changing mirror]